# Updating IMPORTRANGE based on date

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, importrange

I have a spreadsheet I have created with multiple tabs for users to input data on Wednesday of each week. I have a cover worksheet with an IMPORTRANGE formula to pull the data from the users sheets so it can be summarised.

Within each users sheets there are a list of tasks to be completed within a week range (Tues-Mon). Each week has been set in every 2nd column (A,C,E,G...) so the formula looks like:

Is there a way to add in a statement that checks the current date and can modify the formula to change A1:A11 to C1:C11 (E1:E11, G1:G11...) and so on each week?

Comment: Not sure why it didn't post with the example:

=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uWnsKhhahqkQDuwbnCj4u76t1Q6BOF336WKsSTpDs/edit#gid=1253832529","Cain!A1:A11")

Comment: Is this what you meant `=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uWnsKhhahqkQDuwbnCj4u76t1Q6BOF336WKsSTpDs","Cain!A1:A11")`. FYI, this returns "Spreadsheet cannot be found".

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `importrange()` is an `A1` style range reference as a text string, so you can choose which columns to import by using string manipulation to modify the text string.

Another way to do the same is to wrap the import function in `filter()` to choose which columns to include.

Implementation details depend on the particulars of your data and its headers.

Comment: _so you can choose which columns to import by using string manipulation to modify the text string_ & _to choose which columns to include_. But isn't this is heart of the OP's question? _How_ exactly does one use string manipulation to define the text string/address?

Comment: Your answer shows one way to do that assuming that column locations remain fixed. The `filter()` approach would probably offer more flexibility and be easier to maintain, but implementation details depend on the particulars of the data and its headers, which have not been given.

Answer (score 0):

The following explains a technique that will enable you to construct an `IMPORTRANGE()` formula using a dynamic range address.

- The first example (long-form) shows every step in the calculation.

  - the key is the use of `WEEKNUM()` to identify the relevant week, and then adjust that against the column numbers.
  - this approach also coverts the column number to an alpha character in order to  construct the cell address.
- The second example is a compact formula using the principles/logic of the long-form method.

---

**EXAMPLE#1 - long-form**

[image: long form]

**SAMPLE DATA  (Sheet2)**

[image: sample data]

---

**EXAMPLE#2 - short-form**

- Enter the url in Cell B1.
- Enter the sheet names in Row2
- Enter this formula in Row 3 (cell B3, and copy to C3, D3, etc)
  `=importrange($B$1,B2&"!"&regexextract(address(1,(((weeknum(today(),12))-(weeknum("2/8/22",12))+1)*2)-1),"[A-Z]+")&1&":"&regexextract(address(1,(((weeknum(today(),12))-(weeknum("2/8/22",12))+1)*2)-1),"[A-Z]+")&11)`

[image: short form]